# What changes need to be made in CMakeLists.txt when the package is located at some custom location?

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, build

I'm trying to build one repo that has dependencies on OpenCV. In the `CMakeLists.txt`, I can see the following:

```
find_package(OpenCV 3.0 QUIET)
if(NOT OpenCV_FOUND)
   find_package(OpenCV 2.4.3 QUIET)
   if(NOT OpenCV_FOUND)
      message(FATAL_ERROR "OpenCV > 2.4.3 not found.")
   endif()
endif()

# ...

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
   ${OpenCV_LIBS}
   ${EIGEN3_LIBS}
   # ...
)
```

If I'm not wrong, this should have worked without any issues if the OpenCV had been installed in the `/usr/local/opencv` directory. However, the problem is OpenCV on my Linux machine (Ubuntu 18.04) is located at some custom location e.g. `/usr/local/my_opencv/`.

Most probably because of this, when I try to build the repo, I'm getting an error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:<line number> (message):
  OpenCV > 2.4.3 not found.
```

What changes do I need to make in order to get rid of this error and be able to build the repo?

This is what the directory structure of my OpenCV looks like:

```
milan@my_machine:/usr/local/my_opencv$ tree -L 5
.
├── bin
│   ├── opencv_annotation
│   └── ...
├── include
│   └── opencv4
│       └── opencv2
│           ├── ...
│           ├── core
│           │   ├── ...
│           │   ├── core_c.h
│           │   ├── core.hpp
│           │   └── ...
│           ├── core.hpp
│           ├── ...
│           └── ...
├── lib
│   ├── cmake
│   │   └── opencv4
│   │       ├── OpenCVConfig.cmake
│   │       └── ...
│   ├── ...
│   ├── libopencv_core.so -> libopencv_core.so.4.2
│   ├── libopencv_core.so.4.2 -> libopencv_core.so.4.2.0
│   ├── libopencv_core.so.4.2.0
│   ├── ...
│   ├── opencv4
│   │   └── 3rdparty
│   │       ├── ...
│   │       └── ...
│   ├── ...
│   └── python3.6
│       └── dist-packages
│           └── cv2
└── share
    ├── licenses
    │   └── opencv4
    │       ├── ...
    │       └── ...
    └── opencv4
        ├── ...
        │   └── ...
        ├── ...
        └── ...
```

Comment: `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is your friend.

Comment: @SpacePotatoes Thanks for your comment. In my `CMakeLists.txt` file, right before `find_package(OpenCV 3.0 QUIET)`, I put `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH(/usr/local/my_opencv/lib/cmake/opencv4)`. However, it's giving me an error: `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:<line number> (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH):
  Unknown CMake command "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH".`

Comment: `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is not a command but a CMake variable: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html. It's usually set externally by consumers during CMake configuration to help `find_package()` locating CMake config files of dependencies (like `OpenCVConfig.cmake` for example...). It is also used by other commands like `find_library()`, `find_file()`, `find_path()` & `find_program()`.

Comment: @SpacePotatoes I forgot to mention here but I tried passing the command: `cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/my_opencv/lib/cmake/opencv4`. But, got the same error: `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:<line number> (message):   OpenCV > 2.4.3 not found`.

Answer (score 2):

##### You might be able to achieve this without modifying CMakeLists.txt files

(and this might even be preferred, since you've specified that this has to do with idiosyncrasies of your local machine's setup)

If the package uses the Config mode of `find_package`, then you may be able to use [`<PackageName>_ROOT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PackageName_ROOT.html) (variable or env variable), [`CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html) , or set a `<PackageName>_DIR` variable. See [the "Config Mode Search Procedure" docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#config-mode-search-procedure) steps #1, #2, and #3 respectively and the table at the top of that section on what subdirectories are searched. In your case, try setting the value of those variables to `/usr/local/my_opencv`.

Variables can be set in CMakeLists.txt files with `set()`, or as cache variable on the commandline with [`-D`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-D). You can put this info into a [CMakeUserPresets.json](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) file to ease running repeated/multiple configurations.

##### Otherwise (Module mode or if you insist)

You can either take those same above approaches and just set/append-to those variables in the CMakeLists.txt files instead of initializing them via commandline, or if the package uses Config mode, you can also consider using the `PATHS` parameter.

If the package uses Module mode, there are much fewer options. You  could probably write [a dependency provider](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_language.html#dependency-providers) to do this.

- [Docs for `find_package` modes](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-modes)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I really appreciate that. In my `CMakeLists.txt` file, right before `find_package(OpenCV 3.0 QUIET)`, I put `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH(/usr/local/my_opencv/lib/cmake/opencv4)`. However, it's giving me an error: `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:<line number> (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH):
  Unknown CMake command "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH".`

Comment: As an experiment, I didn't update `CMakeLists.txt` and tried passing the command: `cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/my_opencv/lib/cmake/opencv4`. But, got the same error: `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:<line number> (message):
  OpenCV > 2.4.3 not found.`

Comment: see the docs I linked. `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is not a command. it's a variable. As I stated, you set variables using the `set()` command (ex. `set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /usr/local/my_opencv/lib/cmake/opencv4)` (but really I'd do [`list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /usr/local/my_opencv/lib/cmake/opencv4)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html#append))), or the `-D` commandline flag, or in a CMakeUserSettings.json file.

Comment: @Milan I don't know why your attempt with `-D` isn't working though. Try re-running with a fresh variable cache? ([`--fresh`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-fresh)) or try setting it instead to `/usr/local/my_opencv`. I think that might work (see the table under the https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#config-mode-search-procedure docs heading)

Comment: Did you mean `cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/my_opencv/lib/cmake/opencv4 --fresh`? If yes then that didn't work. I even tried changing it to `/usr/local/my_opencv`. But that didn't work either.

Comment: In `CMakeLists.txt`, I made your suggested changes and tried adding `list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /usr/local/my_opencv/lib/cmake/opencv4)`. But got the same error: `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:<line number> (message):
  OpenCV > 2.4.3 not found.`

Comment: Try [debugging the find process](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-debug-find). You can [reach me in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/11107541). Comments are not really for hashing out specific problems like this.

Comment: Maybe it fails because you are forcing find_package to find OpenCV 3.0 then OpenCV 2.0, while you obviously have installed OpenCV 4 (no doubt when I see so versions, and includedir structure you show).

Comment: @SpacePotatoes I tried changing `find_package(OpenCV 3.0 QUIET)` to `find_package(OpenCV 4.0 QUIET)` as well as `find_package(OpenCV 2.4.3 QUIET)` to `find_package(OpenCV 4.2.0 QUIET)`. But still getting the same error. It's not able to find OpenCV stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set [`OpenCV_DIR`](https://cmake-basis.github.io/apidoc/latest/FindOpenCV_8cmake.html#ada6420b29c1b6c4d4c59c6563854b4bd) before to call `find_package`.

```
set(OpenCV_DIR /path/to/opencv)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my `CMakeLists.txt` file, right before `find_package(OpenCV 3.0 QUIET)`, I put `set(OpenCV_DIR /usr/local/my_opencv)`. However, it's still giving me the same error: `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:<line number> (message):
  OpenCV > 2.4.3 not found.`